# GROUP BY error in SQL Oracle with two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am having a rough time with a SQL query. Here is the question:

12. For every invoice, display the invoice number, invoice date
    and the total dollar amount for all products purchased in the invoice, 
    ordered by invoice number in descending order and then by invoice
    date in ascending order.

I'm trying to do a GROUP BY between two tables, INVOICE and LINE, using a SUM function. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT INV_NUMBER, INV_DATE, SUM(LINE_PRICE) AS TOTAL_PRICE
FROM LINE, INVOICE
GROUP BY INV_NUMBER
ORDER BY INV_NUMBER DESC;
```

INV_NUM is in both the LINE and INVOICE tables. So I try doing this as well, with no luck:

```
SELECT INVOICE.INV_NUMBER, INV_DATE, SUM(LINE_PRICE) AS TOTAL_PRICE
FROM LINE, INVOICE
GROUP BY INVOICE.INV_NUMBER
ORDER BY INVOICE.INV_NUMBER DESC;
```

I keep getting an error saying:

Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 28
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:
*Action:

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Jon

Comment: (1) Use explicit `join` syntax.  You are creating a cartesian product.  (2) All non-aggregated columns need to be in the `select`.

Comment: Then were does the aggregated column go? This textbook doesn't cover how to do this with a group by statement...

Comment: When I do this, I get the same error:

SELECT LINE.INV_NUMBER, INV_DATE, SUM(LINE_PRICE)
FROM LINE CROSS JOIN INVOICE
GROUP BY LINE.INV_NUMBER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would actually have a Cartesian result as you have no join condition between the tables.  Next, the GROUP BY is supposed to be by all columns that are not part of any aggregates (sum, count, min, max, avg, etc).  So, you have to group by both the invoice number AND the date as suggested by Julian.  Now that said, yes, an invoice number should be unique and on a single date, so if grouping by the invoice and extra date field, the date would be the same regardless of line items at the detail level.  That being said... try the following, and I'm guessing on the join column basis, but you can adjust that

```
SELECT 
      I.INV_NUMBER, 
      I.INV_DATE, 
      SUM(L.LINE_PRICE) AS TOTAL_PRICE
   FROM 
      INVOICE I
         JOIN LINE L
            ON I.INV_NUMBER = L.INV_NUMBER
   GROUP BY 
      I.INV_NUMBER,
      I.INV_DATE
   ORDER BY 
      I.INV_NUMBER DESC,
      I.INV_DATE
```

Comment: That was pretty much exactly it; i posted an answer just now but yours is pretty much right on. If you can, could you explain why my initial answer wouldn't work, even when I added the INV_DATE to the GROUP BY? I'd appreciate it, and thanks!

Comment: @JonathanJergens, the reason is probably due to a Cartesian result.  Without any join condition between the tables, it was taking each record from one table and joining to EVERY record in the other.  Thus each record would have every date and just be a mess.  At least that is what I suspect without seeing actual data and sample results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT INV_NUMBER, INV_DATE, SUM(LINE_PRICE) AS TOTAL_PRICE
FROM LINE
JOIN INVOICE USING (INV_NUMBER)
GROUP BY INV_NUMBER
ORDER BY INV_NUMBER DESC
```

This works for MySQL/MariaDB if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled. Otherwise use one of these:

```
SELECT INV_NUMBER, MIN(INV_DATE) AS INV_DATE, SUM(LINE_PRICE) AS TOTAL_PRICE
FROM LINE
JOIN INVOICE USING (INV_NUMBER)
GROUP BY INV_NUMBER
ORDER BY INV_NUMBER DESC

SELECT INV_NUMBER, INV_DATE, SUM(LINE_PRICE) AS TOTAL_PRICE
FROM LINE
JOIN INVOICE USING (INV_NUMBER)
GROUP BY INV_NUMBER, INV_DATE
ORDER BY INV_NUMBER DESC
```

Comment: I still get the same error, that it isn't a group by expression

Answer (score 0):

Here was the answer; a friend of mine was able to help out, though I'm still not sure why what I was doing was not working:

```
SELECT LINE.INV_NUMBER, SUM(LINE_PRICE) AS TOTAL_PRICE, INV_DATE
FROM LINE JOIN INVOICE ON (LINE.INV_NUMBER = INVOICE.INV_NUMBER)
GROUP BY LINE.INV_NUMBER, INV_DATE
ORDER BY LINE.INV_NUMBER DESC, INV_DATE ASC;
```

Much thanks to those who tried helping me. I really appreciate it!

Jon